# nginx + php fpm -> 404 php pages - file not found

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

```
*2037 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

 server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name .site.com;
    root /var/www/site;
    error_page 404 /404.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    index index.html index.php;


    if ($http_host != "www.site.com") {
             rewrite ^ http://www.site.com$request_uri permanent;
   }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
         fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
         fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
         fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
         fastcgi_read_timeout 240;

        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

   location ~ /(libraries|setup/frames|setup/libs) {
       deny all;
       return 404;
   }

    location ~ ^/uploads/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
             alias /var/www/site/images/missing.gif; 
#i need to modify this to show only missing files. right now it is showing missing for all the files.

    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 20d;
    }

    location /user_uploads/ {
            location ~ .*\.(php)?$
            {
                deny all;
            }
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
             deny  all;
    }
```

}

php-fpm config is default and is not touched.

The problem is little strange for me.
Error pages are showing **File not found** only if they are .php files.
Other error files are clearly calling the 404.php file

site.com/test => calls 404.php
site.com/test.php => File not found.

I am searching and making changes. but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Please post the _complete_ `server` block.

Comment: I have updated the question..

Comment: Does the file `/var/www/site/404.php` actually exist?

Comment: Yes and it displays 404.php's content to wrong links which are not ending with .php `site.com/ind.asp is shown with 404.php`

Comment: i found the solution to my problem. `location ~ ^/uploads/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ {' i want to show the missing.gif if only the file is not available in that location. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: if it is possible, post it as a new answer including answer to my original question. So i can accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on
```

it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ \.php {
    ..
    try_files $uri =404;
    ..
}
```

Add this in php location block to tell nginx to check file exist before sending any request to FastCGI.